# How to install tkinter on windows 10, python 3.6.1

Tags: python, tkinter

I've encountered similar errors while using several different packages like matplotlib and pymc3, error message said:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 115, in <module>
    _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\__init__.py", line 32, in pylab_setup
    globals(),locals(),[backend_name],0)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_tkagg.py", line 6, in <module>
    from six.moves import tkinter as Tk
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 92, in __get__
    result = self._resolve()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 115, in _resolve
    return _import_module(self.mod)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 82, in _import_module
    __import__(name)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tkinter'
```

I'm totally new to python, have no idea what tkinter is. After some googles, I tried to install ActiveTcl 8.6.4 into default path, but it doesn't work.

What should I do?

Comment: I know this forum isn't to post opinion based stuff but I'll say it anyways because it might help you a lot in the future. Try start using Linux systems to code (Ubuntu, Mint, whatever you like), it makes lots of things easier and usually tutorials and other stuff are made based on Linux OS. You can put a  dual boot setup and use Linux only for coding (thats what I do).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but my Surface Book cannot run Linux properly. Although I have a virtual machine, it is not convenient to work inside it. But I'll learn to use Linux as soon as I get a PC in my office

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I figured out what happened. I unchecked tcl/tk option before installation, that may be the problem. I modified my python installation just now, hope it could help.